# Why sites has a delay when I'm working with data?

Tags: force.com-sites

I'm working with salesforce sites and I'm inserting some records in a custom object, the problem is when I insert a record it is in salesforce but I need to refresh the page to see my record in my site. It seems like there're a delay between Insert and Show the record. Anyone has a similar problem?

Comment: Are you expecting your site to be dynamic?

Comment: Well, just it is when I'm inserting records I want to be reflected my changes in a table. I checked it out and it seems that with cache="false" in the <apex:page> attribute solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

cache = "false" in apex:page attribute solve the problem.